# Fix all the missing semicolons automatically. (Dart Editor)

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Is it possible to fix all the missing semicolons automatically in Dart Editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently, but we are hard at work on bringing this and other formatting features to the editor and the command line. Stay tuned!

Comment: Any progress? It's so frustrating to force yourself constantly put obvious semicolons after getting used to the modern languages like Scala.